# Am having an issue with pydoc it saying "could not convert string to float: 'import'

Tags: python, pydoc

This is the error that I came up when I ran the pydoc command on the file.

`problem in .\semestProj.py - ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'import'`

I originally ran this on my Windows laptop and then ran it on a Linux system and I still got this error I have searched everywhere but I cant seem to find any solutions for this issue. Btw all my imports statement are on the first line.

[Link to the first couple of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdTL5.png)

Edit

I resolved this I just needed to add the `main` function. I had no idea that pydoc needed a main function

Comment: Can you please share the relevant part of your `semstProj.py` script, where you use `import`? :)

Comment: Hey I added a link to the first couple of lines

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why not upload images of code and/or errors on SO when asking a question [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).